# Looking for Canvas Keyframe Pause Keyframe animation example

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am simply looking for a way to create keyframe animation in canvas to say 
Go left pause go down. Thats it. My entire book and the internets have all sorts of neat fluid animations and interactivity lessons, and css3 has keyframes but I cant find anything for canvas javascript other then plugins or frameworks which i'll use in the future but I want a simple method for now.

```
  (function drawFrame () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ball.x += vx;
    ball.pause(2)// 2 seconds;
    ball.y += vx+1;
    ball.draw(context);
  }());
```

Added the only answer I can figure out right not, nested if conditionals, yuck. I would hate to try and make anything 4+ keyframes based in this setup

```
// Check to see if it reached target
       if (Math.abs(dx) < 1) {
          ball.x = targetX;
          //window.cancelRequestAnimationFrame(animRequest);
          log.value = "Animation done!";

// if it did, now fire off the second keyframe and check if it reached new target
          if(Math.abs(dy) < 1){
            ball.y = targetY;
          } else{
            var vy = dy * easing;
            ball.y += vy;
          }

        } 

// Otherwise continue first keyframe move.
        else {
          var vx = dx * easing;
          ball.x += vx;
        }
        ball.draw(context);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited to provide an animation framework]

**Here is a starter framework I created to do your Keyframe animation**

I have kept it simple, but you can certainly build onto this framework.

You can define 1 or more canvas objects to use in your keyframes like this:

```
        // define a drawing function that will draw your object on the canvas
        var drawFn1=function(context,x,y){
            var radius=30;
            context.strokeStyle="blue";
            context.lineWidth=5;
            context.fillStyle="green";
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.fill();
        }

        // create a new displayobject
        var displayObject1=new DisplayObject(200,100,drawFn1);
```

Then you add 1 or more display objects to an array of objects.  You can keyframe all these objects individually--All objects can have separate animations.

```
        // create an array of DisplayObjects
        var displayObjects=[];

        // push our displayObject1 into displayObjects
        displayObjects.push(displayObject1);
```

Then you add actions that you want your object to do (and durations for those actions to complete).  You can add as many actions in whatever combination as you need.  Right now, I have coded only 2 actions: "move" and "pause".  You can certainly add more actions to the framework.

If needed, you can add actions even as the the current keyframes are playing.  Any added actions are queued for execution after the current actions complete.

The code below will cause the object to:

1. Move left over 20 frames,
2. Pause for 30 frames,
3. Move down over 20 frames.

Notice the actions can be added using chaining.

```
 // add actions for the displayobject
 displayObject1.moveBy(-75,0,20).pause(30).moveBy(0,75,20);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/RjR9C/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:15px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");


        // defines an action to accomplish
        function Action(type,msDuration){
            var type=type;
            var duration=msDuration;
            var incrementalX;
            var incrementalY;
        }


        function DisplayObject(X,Y,Drawfunction){

            this.drawFunction=Drawfunction;
            this.x=X;
            this.y=Y;

            this.actionStack=[];
            this.currentAction=null;
            this.IsActive=false;

        }
        DisplayObject.prototype.pause=function(duration){
            var action=new Action();
            action.type="pause";
            action.duration=duration;
            this.actionStack.push(action)
            this.IsActive=true;
            return(this);
        }
        DisplayObject.prototype.test=function(){
          alert("test");
        }
        DisplayObject.prototype.moveBy=function(offsetX,offsetY,duration){
            var action=new Action();
            action.type="moveBy";
            action.duration=duration;
            action.incrementalX=offsetX/duration;
            action.incrementalY=offsetY/duration;
            this.actionStack.push(action)
            this.IsActive=true;
            return(this);
        }
        DisplayObject.prototype.tick=function(context){

            // If we have nothing to do...outta here!
            if(!this.IsActive){return;};

            //
            if(!this.currentAction){
                this.currentAction=this.actionStack.shift();
            }

            // animate the current frame
            this.doNextFrame(context);

            // decrement the tick countdown on our current action
            this.currentAction.duration--;

            // if this action is done then load the next action
            if(this.currentAction.duration<=0){
                if(this.actionStack.length>0){
                    this.currentAction=this.actionStack.shift();
                }else{
                    this.currentAction=null;
                    this.IsActive=false;
                }
            }

        }
        DisplayObject.prototype.doNextFrame=function(context){

            // update based on currentAction
            switch(this.currentAction.type){
                case "pause":
                    break;
                case "moveBy":
                    this.x+=this.currentAction.incrementalX;
                    this.y+=this.currentAction.incrementalY;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            // draw ourself
            this.drawFunction(context,this.x,this.y);

        }


        //  Here’s how you make use of this AnimationFrame framework

        var drawFn1=function(context,x,y){
            var radius=30;
            context.strokeStyle="blue";
            context.lineWidth=5;
            context.fillStyle="green";
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.stroke();
            context.fill();
        }
        // create a new displayobject
        var displayObject1=new DisplayObject(200,100,drawFn1);
        // add actions for the displayobject
        displayObject1.moveBy(-75,0,20).pause(30).moveBy(0,75,20);


        // create an array of DisplayObjects
        var displayObjects=[];
        // push our displayObject1 into displayObjects
        displayObjects.push(displayObject1);

        function runOneFrame(){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            for(var i=0;i<displayObjects.length;i++){
                displayObjects[i].tick(ctx);
            }
        }

        var fps = 20;
        function Ticker() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimationFrame(Ticker);
                runOneFrame();
            }, 1000/fps);
        }

        $("#go").click(function () { Ticker(); $("#go").hide(); });        

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="go">Begin animation frames</button><br/>
    <p>The display will go left, pause and go down.</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You! Though I am confused on how setTimeout wrapping the requestAnimationFrame will keep proper time. I thought that was the entire point of requestAnimationFrame to replace setTimeout since it's not based of close proximity time just browser event bubbles

Comment: A good read thank you, however it does not really solve the riddle. I added some nested if conditionals code above, it's been the only thing I can figure out by mashing chapter files from the book apress html5 animation together. Is this really the only solution in a no framework javascript way?

Comment: OK, see my edited answer.  I coded a javascript framework that will do your keyframe animations.  Feel free to use/add to it to fit your needs.

Comment: OH AWESOME! I will check it out right now, thank you! As you were typing I kinda sorta got something to work as I re-re-re-read if conditionals rules and read a lot of blogs to sorta get a working example.  But I honestly just futzed with vars and tired a counter thing. Not sure what the design patteren would be called. http://jsfiddle.net/Wv9Gw/

Comment: I can't up vote you enough! So will just say ULTRA UNICORN RAINBOWS THANK YOU! I have much to read and learn from now. Thank you again.